# Efficient way to place driver.wait in selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class menupageProperty{
  public static WebElement administrativeModule(WebDriver driver) {
   private static WebElement menuElement= null; 
   menuElement= driver.findElement(By.linkText("ADMINISTRATIVE MODULE"));
   return menuElement;
  }
  public static WebElement editModule(WebDriver driver) {
   private static WebElement menuElement= null; 
   menuElement= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit MODULE"));
   return menuElement;
  }
}

public class runAutomation {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    menupageProperty.administrative_Module(driver).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    menupageProperty.userMgmtClick(driver).click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    menupageProperty.edituser(driver).click();
 }
}
```

I have such element. I want to place thread.sleep in between or wait time in two clicks. Currently I am hard coding that as Thread.sleep(4000). Please help me to write in efficient way or rather it's not correct way to place Thread.sleep.

Comment: Just use the `Driver.wait` method, it will wait for the element to load.

Comment: This is the few elements from one page I have around 48 Page web element. How would i explicitly say Driver.wait for x seconds? Also approximately I know 4-7 sec to load each web element. But in my code i do not want to hard code Driver.wait for (x) seconds in between two click

Comment: You Google "Selenium + Driver.Wait" and review the documentation and examples.

Comment: Just use fluentwait , it will wait until the items not appeared

Comment: Based on above code example can you give me some sample code here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something like this:

```
void waitForElementToLoad(WebElement webElement) {
    WebElement element = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement));
}
```

Pass in the element you're waiting for on the next click and wait for it to be clickable. This should eliminate the need to hard code a time for each and you can depend on the webDriverWait time you specify.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use implicit wait here , as a good practise, if there is
>   certain element within the clicks then you can use fluentwait it will
>   poll the element in given interval for given  time  you can read about
>   [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/)

sample code:

```
// Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking

  // for its presence once every 5 seconds.

  Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)

    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)

    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)

    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

  WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {

    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {

    return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));

    }

   });
```

Comment: Based on above code example can you give me some sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will wait until the element is shown in the DOM

Ps: it is not a good practice to expose the driver and pass it as parameter

```
public void waitIfNotPresent(WebElement element) {
        webElementWait.until(driver -> {
            try {
                return !element.isDisplayed();
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you suggest to avoid to expose driver as you said in your comments. Currently what I am doing is I have object Library for each page as a stranded way we collect by inspecting web page. As shown in above question using that in the main class to click.
Can you please help me to over come as I am at very initial stage at building of automation framework. Will be great help

Comment: Just use it in one class and call only this and use page pattern

Comment: What do you suggest to avoid to expose driver as you said in your comments. Currently what I am doing is I have object Library for each page as a stranded way we collect by inspecting web page. As shown in above question using that in the main class to click. Can you please help me to over come as I am at very initial stage at building of automation framework. Will be great help

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `wait` for elements to load

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='Welcome']")));
```

But if you want to wait until some ajax request is completed then use this

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(new  ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() 
{ public Boolean apply(WebDriver  driver) 
{ JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0"); 
}

});
```